# How many Layers in the original Yoon Kim CNN implementation?

Tags: keras, cnn, convolutional-neural-network

I saw some implementations of Yoon Kim's Convolutional Neural Network (Paper: http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/D14-1181)....

...in some implementations they put one more Dense(..) Layer before the output layer (with softmax activation). In my opinion there is no additional Dense(..) Layer in the original paper:

So what's the original implementation?

[image: differing Yoon Kim CNN implementations]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the model architecture from original paper below, it looks like there is just one dense layer at the end. Conv layers --> Max Pool over time --> Dense

[image]

Comment: I‘m of the same opinion.  So would you put the dropout after the flatten()?

Comment: Yes, I think dropout comes after flatten. I implemented this in Pytorch, and I used Conv --> Maxpool --> Concat (in this case it  is similar to flatten in Keras) --> Dropout --> Dense